# how to assign data files path in sql server when creating new web application in share point

Tags: development, powershell, sharepoint-server, sql-server-2012

recently we migrated storage of all sql server databases to diffrent storage.

and mounted back all content databases , and now sharepoint farm is working fine but,

when i try to create new web app i faced error.

I am facing strange issue:

-- When we create new web application in my test server the data file and log file create by default below in this path

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

but In our production servers environment ,

in sql server  if we assign the log file  path manually the databases created .(O/LOG/MSSQL/

when i creating new sql database in sql server: i should give path manually for log file

but how i tell sharepoint that create data files in specific path in sql server when creating new

web application , where can i configure this

adil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify this in SQL.

1. Open SQL Management Studio
2. Connect to SQL database server
3. Right click and select Properties
4. Choose Database Settings
5. Change `Database default locations`

From now onwards all new database files goes to new location

Comment: I tried database setting when i change default location path for log file and data file its not take affect , again it shows old path

Comment: Tried restarting database services?